# Visualizing longitudinal data with a trajectory/best-fitting mean growth curve and a spaghetti plot using R

Tags: r, plot, visualization, best-fit-curve

I have a longitudinal dataset with two groups of diagnoses I want to visually compare. Each subject has either one, two, or three data points and a number of dependent variables.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
dput(sample)
```

> structure(list(id = structure(c(61L, 7L, 7L, 14L, 14L, 43L, 43L, 
>   64L, 65L, 65L, 67L, 68L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
>   8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
>   20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 27L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
>   30L, 30L, 33L, 33L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 45L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 55L, 55L, 
>   56L, 62L, 32L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 
>   44L, 44L, 44L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 52L, 
>   52L, 52L, 53L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 57L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 63L, 
>   63L, 63L, 66L, 9L, 9L, 16L, 16L, 25L, 26L, 28L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
>   34L, 34L, 35L, 35L), .Label = c("101", "104", "105", "106", "107", 
>   "108", "11 ", "110", "111", "112", "114", "116", "117", "12 ", 
>   "120", "121", "127", "128", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", 
>   "139", "141", "144", "146", "151", "153", "158", "159", "16 ", 
>   "160", "161", "164", "17 ", "175", "180", "22 ", "23 ", "27 ", 
>   "32 ", "33 ", "34 ", "4  ", "41 ", "42 ", "44 ", "45 ", "46 ", 
>   "5  ", "52 ", "54 ", "57 ", "6  ", "7  ", "71 ", "73 ", "75 ", 
>   "77 ", "8  ", "9  ", "91 ", "93 ", "95 ", "96 ", "97 ", "98 "
>   ), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CON  ", 
>   "PAT  "), class = "factor"), timepoint = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
>   2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
>   2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
>   1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
>   1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
>   1L, 2L), .Label = c("    1.00", "    2.00", "    3.00", "   2.00 "
>   ), class = "factor"), age = c(12.64722222, 15.89444444, 16.38333333, 
>   12.76666667, 13.25555556, 12.03888889, 12.03888889, 14.11944444, 
>   8.355555556, 9.311111111, 12.73888889, 12.27777778, 14.55277778, 
>   15.54166667, 16.53055556, 12.53055556, 14.53888889, 14.36666667, 
>   15.57222222, 12.93055556, 9.152777778, 8.552777778, 10.725, 15.16944444, 
>   16.22777778, 15.875, 17.19166667, 11.88888889, 12.87777778, 8.161111111, 
>   12.80833333, 10.86944444, 9.133333333, 14.51666667, 13.58333333, 
>   14.98333333, 17.42777778, 18.42777778, 19.425, 12.81388889, 8.227777778, 
>   14.86111111, 15.8391933, 17.48888889, 15.73055556, 16.68611111, 
>   17.64501522, 15.63611111, 16.80277778, 14.09444444, 15.13006088, 
>   15.21666667, 16.14269406, 9.2, 10.74444444, 13.34, 14.52222222, 
>   15.64166667, 11.49166667, 12.48888889, 12.81, 15.70277778, 13.83333333, 
>   17.09722222, 18.15555556, 19.22222222, 9.727777778, 15.32222222, 
>   16.8, 14.40833333, 15.36944444, 15.91111111, 16.96666667, 15.61944444, 
>   16.72777778, 17.725, 14.69722222, 16.99037291, 9.077777778, 10.07222222, 
>   12.94520548, 15.01944444, 16.81944444, 17.925, 18.88333333, 13.50277778, 
>   14.65555556, 15.77222222, 15.79166667, 16.86111111, 15.90833333, 
>   16.8206621, 16.03611111, 17.03337139, 9.583561644, 15.48888889, 
>   16.46666667, 14.83055556, 16.32777778, 17.30585997, 18.31944444, 
>   10.47222222, 16.29722222, 18.77222222, 10.07777778, 11.30277778, 
>   7.444444444, 13.69863014, 6.261111111, 15.66944444, 16.65555556, 
>   17.64459665, 17.63611111, 17.51944444, 10.775, 11.81111111), 
>       vol = c(548972.1775, 648425.585, 615478.6595, 601188.9513, 
>       606759.7861, 598821.7733, 582035.8968, 475477.9975, 574780.474, 
>       567670.6336, 623036.5768, 603722.0278, 526709.9175, 509533.1299, 
>       516068.5599, 525279.5766, 558883.6295, 612427.3156, 599934.9009, 
>       591680.4761, 639770.0607, 558242.4347, 549221.9145, 605292.8799, 
>       550536.2854, 511179.4063, 483482.6999, 558609.3465, 523856.3622, 
>       576197.7365, 537253.1676, 627511.0046, 501817.1233, 616762.9889, 
>       605997.8985, 582158.3157, 523472.5022, 504760.7745, 503067.4078, 
>       646116.6452, 580252.1451, 597486.9348, 626396.6821, 572584.2842, 
>       573443.347, 579332.7002, 473260.9821, 534797.636, 526065.6489, 
>       560880.908, 542218.4166, 630812.8165, 629211.68, 608299.9884, 
>       656401.4787, 571348.4899, 560327.5263, 543939.9021, 596117.8705, 
>       584485.7293, 556320.8872, 626296.7889, 584663.1206, 656435.4865, 
>       660134.5144, 643119.3113, 576699.6893, 531707.7736, 530264.4315, 
>       541777.7762, 530922.3088, 610626.5987, 599960.3038, 650468.3647, 
>       636040.7153, 635297.0107, 641780.0158, 599630.4608, 568276.3797, 
>       574587.6778, 496635.5676, 539622.8043, 532498.2519, 516473.2384, 
>       517793.2922, 535472.7677, 528296.0881, 523785.7416, 534744.7207, 
>       524431.1189, 587735.5674, 582148.4209, 571915.1305, 568074.2646, 
>       581270.9412, 560716.9028, 532420.9127, 589196.387, 548777.309, 
>       550087.9959, 539554.4263, 684722.458, 529343.8186, 546955.3154, 
>       660572.5684, 660768.0026, 572548.3249, 598619.7422, 565051.5456, 
>       596404.2088, 586308.6217, 592881.4289, 531294.8592, 543588.604, 
>       644262.9365, 636280.5823)), .Names = c("id", "group", "timepoint", 
>   "age", "vol"), row.names = c(NA, -116L), class = "data.frame", codepage = 65001L)

I want to visualise each dependent variable (on y-axis) over age (on x-axis) using a trajectory/best-fitting mean growth curve, as well as a spaghetti plot, so it will look something like this:

best-fit mean growth curve and spaghetti plot
[image]

Here is what I have so far:

R code:

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(vol ~ age, groups = id, type= "b", data= data, 
ylab = "Volume (mm cubed)",
xlab = "Age (years)",
main = "Volume",
scales = list (x = list(at = c(4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20))))
```

Output: longitudinal spaghetti plot
[image]

As you can see from the output figure, the plot is grouped by subject (id). I want to keep the lines that connect each time point for each subject, but grouped by diagnosis as shown in the first graph. Also unsure how to create (and overlay) a best-fit mean growth curve on the spaghetti plot.

Finally, after fitting a model for each group, what command in R is best for obtaining summary statistics (i.e. t-test and f-test for p-values)?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data? Paste into your question the output of `dput(my_data_sample)`.

Comment: Just pasted a sample! (sorry it's pretty messy, not sure how to insert a vertical scroll bar!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ggplot2`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = DT, aes(x = age, y = vol)) + 
geom_point(size = 2, aes(color = group)) + #colour points by group
geom_path(aes(group = id)) + #spaghetti plot
stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ x, aes(group = group, colour = group)) + #line of best fit by group
ylab("Volume (mm cubed)") +
xlab("Age (years)") +
theme_bw()
```

We use `geom_path` to replicate the spaghetti plot, `geom_smooth` to create the two lines of best fit, and `geom_point` to colour by diagnosis

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is almost exactly what I need, thank you! Is there a way to overlay the two graphs so the two trajectories can be more easily be compared, as shown in the first picture of my original question? I'd also like the spaghetti plot and best fit curve to be one color for each group (also shown in the first picture, original question). Thanks!

Comment: @nisa sorry about that - misunderstood. Edited now

Comment: Perfect, thank you! And finally, do you know of a command in R best for obtaining summary statistics for the best fit curves (i.e. t-test and f-test for p-values)?

Comment: @Nisa we generally like to keep separate questions as different questions on StackOverflow - if you have a new question you are better off asking it separately - mainly because it will help other people who are having the same issue as you! I would also do a bit of research and see if you can find an existing answer - I imagine it exists. If it doesn't, feel free to link your new question here and I'll take a look at it!